# Percent signs in class file

Tags: document-classes, percent-sign

I am trying to write my own class and I don't quite understand the use of percent signs. For example, I have this snippet of code in my `.cls` file:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}
        \huge\bfseries{foo}
    \end{center}
}
```

However, scanning through examples online, I have noticed the use of percent signs:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{center}
        \huge\bfseries{foo}
    \end{center}%
}
```

These two bits of code seem to work exactly the same. I'm wondering, is there any difference between the two (I'm guessing the `%` sign does not have the same meaning that is has in `.tex` files)?

Comment: The `%` sign has the same meaning that it has in `.tex` files, to comment characters till the end of current line, including the end-of-line character.

Comment: the highest ranked question if you search for "percent" is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat